# Trying to populate list using scala and lift

Tags: scala, lift

I am trying to populate a list using scala and lift and am getting a class not found exception. The code is directly out of the Lift in Action book.

Here is the snippet code with dummy data included which is what should be getting displayed.

```
import scala.xml.NodeSeq
import net.liftweb.util.Helpers._
object Library {
  case class Book(name: String)
  case class Author(name: String, books: List[Book])
  val books = List(
    Author("JK Rowling", List(
      Book("Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows"),
      Book("Harry Potter and the Goblet of Fire"))
    ),
    Author("Joshua Suereth", List(
      Book("Scala in Depth"))
    )
) }
class Authors {
def list =
    "ul" #> Library.books.map { author =>
      ".name" #> author.name &
      ".books" #> ("li *" #> author.books.map(_.name))
   }
}
```

Here is the HTML code which should display a list of authors with their books.

```
<ul lift="authors.list">
  <li><span class="name">Author</span>
    <ul class="books">
      <li>Book title</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

When I run I get this error:

```
Error processing snippet: authors.list 
Reason: Class Not Found
```

Any ideas as to what is going wrong?

Comment: what package is your snippet located in? Unless otherwise configured, snippets are, by default, looked up in the `snippet` package

Comment: I actually got this to work. I had embedded the code in something else to test and used the wrong path for the lookup. So I guess this can be closed.

Answer (score 1):

authors requires a capital A to match the object name.

Must be

`<ul lift="Authors.list">
     ...
   </ul>`